# Weblogic 12c unable to parse class file hikaricp-3.4.5 module-info.class

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, weblogic12c

I am trying deploy a spring boot application to WebLogic 12c server, but it gives following errors:

```
Unable to parse class file: zip:/lfs/wwwmnt/wabe-Q7aZsBnB-t-app_node1/clusterDomain/servers/AdminSer
ver/tmp/_WL_user/hst-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-2/b26a1z/war/WEB-INF/lib/HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/module-info.class
```

I have tried with different jdbc version but still cannot resolve this error.

Any suggestion how to fix that?

1. SpringBoot 2.4.0
2. hibernateVersion 5.4.24.final
3. oracleJDBC 19.8.0.0
4. Weblogic 12c
5. Gradle

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to the fact that this library is developed using java 11 ( but also backward compatible with java 8 ) - it contains this file that defines a module in java 11. And I guess your weblogic has java 8 and then it cannot read this file and reports this error. But that doesn't mean the app won't work, like in my case where I have 4.0.3 with the same error in Weblogic server logs, but app is running ok.